# Google Colab Error : Failed to get convolution algorithm.This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

UnknownError: Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.

```
 [[{{node conv2d_1/convolution}} = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NCHW", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="VALID", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](zero_padding2d_1/Pad, conv2d_1/kernel/read)]]
 [[{{node metrics/acc/Mean/_255}} = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_563_metrics/acc/Mean", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
```

This error I am getting on Google colab. Colab's tensorflow version is 1.12.0.

I couldn't find any solution. Cause All of them were of local system.

Comment: Can you share a self-contained notebook that reproduces the error you observe?

Comment: Did you and how did you fix this problem?

Comment: I've received the same error. It seems the error only shows when you've assign a GPU. I don't get the error when I train a model using CPU.

Answer (score 1):

For future passers-by, this looks like a service bug that is being addressed by the Colab folks now.

Details are on [the GitHub issue](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/384).

**Update**: This issue has been fixed service-side. Details: https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/384#issuecomment-451001849

Comment: it is not resolved.  getting this nasty error.

Answer (score 0):

Just install tensorflow and dont install CUDA and cuDNN

This was my first code(Which had the error occurring)

`!pip uninstall tensorflow`

`!pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.15`

`!apt install --allow-change-held-packages libcudnn7=7.4.1.5-1+cuda10.0`

By removing the last line my error got resolved

`!pip uninstall tensorflow`

`!pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.15`

Hope it helps!