# Keras - UnknownError: Failed to get convolution algorithm

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

While working with Keras and Jupyter Notebook, I occasionally get an error (see below for entire error log) once I  start training a model. While [Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53698035/failed-to-get-convolution-algorithm-this-is-probably-because-cudnn-failed-to-in) suggests that this is related to a version conflict, it does not seem to apply in my case. In my case, my versions seem to be working as I am able to run the training procedure just fine most of the time, however once I get this error I need to close all running python processes and restart Anaconda in order to proceed without errors.

Since restarting Anaconda each time this error occurs is very unhandy, I wonder if there is any fix or suggestion on why this error occurs other than a version conflict?

This is the entire error I am getting:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnknownError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-5d485feb54c5> in <module>
      1 K.clear_session()
      2 model_all = define_model(train_data)
----> 3 model_all = train_bild(train_generator_all,validation_generator_all, model_all)
      4 model_all.save(subdir+cat+"/"+cat+"_model_all_inception.h5")
      5 

<ipython-input-17-afb528e9309d> in train_bild(train_generator, validation_generator, model)
     25         epochs=num_epochs,
     26         validation_data=validation_generator,
---> 27         validation_steps=VALID_STEPS, workers=16,callbacks=[checker,early, reduce_lr],class_weight=class_weights)#,class_weight=class_weights)
     28 
     29     model = load_model(filepath)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     89                 warnings.warn('Update your `' + object_name + '` call to the ' +
     90                               'Keras 2 API: ' + signature, stacklevel=2)
---> 91             return func(*args, **kwargs)
     92         wrapper._original_function = func
     93         return wrapper

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in fit_generator(self, generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch)
   1416             use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing,
   1417             shuffle=shuffle,
-> 1418             initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
   1419 
   1420     @interfaces.legacy_generator_methods_support

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_generator.py in fit_generator(model, generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch)
    215                 outs = model.train_on_batch(x, y,
    216                                             sample_weight=sample_weight,
--> 217                                             class_weight=class_weight)
    218 
    219                 outs = to_list(outs)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in train_on_batch(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight)
   1215             ins = x + y + sample_weights
   1216         self._make_train_function()
-> 1217         outputs = self.train_function(ins)
   1218         return unpack_singleton(outputs)
   1219 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py in __call__(self, inputs)
   2713                 return self._legacy_call(inputs)
   2714 
-> 2715             return self._call(inputs)
   2716         else:
   2717             if py_any(is_tensor(x) for x in inputs):

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py in _call(self, inputs)
   2673             fetched = self._callable_fn(*array_vals, run_metadata=self.run_metadata)
   2674         else:
-> 2675             fetched = self._callable_fn(*array_vals)
   2676         return fetched[:len(self.outputs)]
   2677 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1437           ret = tf_session.TF_SessionRunCallable(
   1438               self._session._session, self._handle, args, status,
-> 1439               run_metadata_ptr)
   1440         if run_metadata:
   1441           proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py in __exit__(self, type_arg, value_arg, traceback_arg)
    526             None, None,
    527             compat.as_text(c_api.TF_Message(self.status.status)),
--> 528             c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
    529     # Delete the underlying status object from memory otherwise it stays alive
    530     # as there is a reference to status from this from the traceback due to

UnknownError: Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.
     [[{{node conv2d_1/convolution}} = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@batch_normalization_1/cond_1/FusedBatchNorm/Switch"], data_format="NCHW", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="VALID", strides=[1, 1, 2, 2], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](conv2d_1/convolution-0-TransposeNHWCToNCHW-LayoutOptimizer, conv2d_1/kernel/read)]]
     [[{{node loss/mul/_4005}} = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_4855_loss/mul", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
```

Comment: Did you solve this?  I have the same issue where it has worked flawlessly, then got stuck in a failure loop somehow.  This link has some mysterious code you can drop in to fix, but it annoys me that I have to do it:  https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/24828

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem several times, all of them it was due to a dirty log file that the Saver was trying to restore - the only solution was to delete the last model checkpoint file and restart from the previous one (also removing the line referring the last one in the checkpoint.txt file).

Probably this happens when during the model saving something happens (the saver processed dies - something changes the file while is still in writing, ...)

Answer (score 0):

The misterious code (linked by Mastiff in the comment) from https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/24828 is this:

```
# python 3.6 and tensorflow (both 1.x and 2.0)
def allow_gpu_memory_growth(log_device_placement=True):
    """
    Allow dynamic memory growth (by default, tensorflow allocates all gpu memory).
    This sometimes fixes the 
    <<Error : Failed to get convolution algorithm. 
    This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, 
    so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above>>. 
    May hurt performance slightly (see https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu).

    Usage: Run before any other code.

    :param log_device_placement: set True to log device placement (on which device the operation ran)
    :return:None
    """
    from tensorflow.compat.v1.keras.backend import set_session
    config = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto()
    config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True  # dynamically grow the memory used on the GPU
    config.log_device_placement = log_device_placement
    sess = tf.compat.v1.Session(config=config)
    set_session(sess)
```