# Tensorflow/Keras: Unknown: Failed to get convolution algorithm

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have the following hardware/Software:

- NVIDIA RTX2060 6GB
- Cuda 10

I would like run the [Keras mnist example](https://keras.io/examples/mnist_cnn/). On my other Computer there works with the same software. I obtain this Error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnknownError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Unknown: Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.
         [[{{node conv2d_1/convolution}}]]
         [[conv2d_19/Sigmoid/_1405]]
  (1) Unknown: Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.
         [[{{node conv2d_1/convolution}}]]
```

Where is my problem?

Comment: Did you install cuda driver? If so, did you set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH env variable appropriately?

Comment: I used Keras on Windows. I set not the LD_LIBRARY_PATH. What is the content of the Variable?

Comment: It indicates the location of installed cuda. Probably it cannot find the cuda.

Comment: C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.0\lib\x64... Is this path correct?

Comment: look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53698035/failed-to-get-convolution-algorithm-this-is-probably-because-cudnn-failed-to-in)

Answer (score 0):

This error usually occurs due to vesion mismatch of CUDA/cudnn. Please follow instructions on link provided: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu. Also if your default python is coming from Anaconda you should install evrything using conda.