# cuDNN producing error failed to initialize

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to train `VGGNET` model on a custom dataset, I have experimented with the model on `colab` but now I need to run the same code on local machine.

I tried to run the code with `Tensorflow GPU 1.15` and `CUDA 10.0` (colab I am using has `Tensorflow GPU 1.15` and `CUDA 10.0`), but the code is giving this error

```
...
  (0) Unknown: Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.
     [[{{node block1_conv1/convolution}}]]
     [[loss/mul/_169]]
...
```

Things I tried

- Tried different version of cuDNN 7.6.4 and 7.4.2
- Tried downgrading Tensorflow GPU to 1.14 from 1.15

I have also gone through these posts [post1](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/failed-to-get-convolution-algorithm-this-is-probably-because-cudnn-failed-to-initialize/67147), [post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53698035/failed-to-get-convolution-algorithm-this-is-probably-because-cudnn-failed-to-in) but I could not be able to resolve the error

System: `Ubuntu 18.04`, `CUDA 10.0`, `cuDNN 7.4.2`, `Nvidia driver 440.64`, `Tensorflow GPU 1.15`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there were some issues with RTX Cards, I had to add few lines of code to make it work

```
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
tf.Session(config=config)
```