# Failed to get convolution algorithm Tensorflow 2.3.0

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, image-processing, deep-learning, computer-vision

I recently finished the Image super-resolution using Autoencoders in Coursera and when I try to run the same code on my laptop using Spyder and Jupyter notebook, I keep getting this error.
I am using **Nvidia GeForce 1650Ti** along with **Tensorflow-gpu=2.3.0, CUDA=10.1, cuDNN=7.6.5 and python=3.8.5**. I have used the same configurations for running many deep neural network problems and none of them gave this error.

Code:

```
# Image Super Resolution using Autoencoder
# Loading the Images
x_train_n = []
x_train_down = []

x_train_n2 = []
x_train_down2 = []

import tensorflow as tf
gpu_options = tf.compat.v1.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.95)
session = tf.compat.v1.Session(config=tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_options))

path = 'D:/GPU testing/Image Super Resolution/data/cars_train/'
images = os.listdir(path)
size = 0
for a in images:
    try:
        img = image.load_img(str(path+a), target_size=(64,64,3))
        img_1 = image.img_to_array(img)
        img_1 = img_1/255.
        x_train_n.append(img_1)
        dwn2 = rescale(rescale(img_1, 0.5, multichannel=True),
                                    2.0, multichannel=True)
        img_2 = image.img_to_array(dwn2)
        x_train_down.append(img_2)
        size+= 1
    except:
        print("Error loading image")
        size += 1
    if size >= 64:
        break

x_train_n2 = np.array(x_train_n)
print(x_train_n2.shape)
x_train_down2 = np.array(x_train_down)
print(x_train_down2.shape)

# Building a Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Dropout, Conv2DTranspose, UpSampling2D, add
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras import regularizers
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, ReduceLROnPlateau

# Building the Encoder
input_img = Input(shape=(64, 64, 3))
l1 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu',
            activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(10e-10))(input_img)
l2 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu',
            activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(10e-10))(l1)

l3 = MaxPooling2D(padding='same')(l2)
l3 = Dropout(0.3)(l3)
l4 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3),  padding='same', activation='relu',
            activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(10e-10))(l3)
l5 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu',
            activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(10e-10))(l4)

l6 = MaxPooling2D(padding='same')(l5)
l7 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu',
            activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(10e-10))(l6)

# Building the Decoder
l8 = UpSampling2D()(l7)

l9 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu',
            activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(10e-10))(l8)
l10 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu',
             activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(10e-10))(l9)

l11 = add([l5, l10])
l12 = UpSampling2D()(l11)
l13 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu',
             activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(10e-10))(l12)
l14 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu',
             activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(10e-10))(l13)

l15 = add([l14, l2])

# chan = 3, for RGB
decoded = Conv2D(3, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu',
                 activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(10e-10))(l15)

# Create our network
autoencoder = Model(input_img, decoded)
autoencoder_hfenn = Model(input_img, decoded)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='mean_squared_error')
autoencoder.summary()

# Training the Model
history = autoencoder.fit(x_train_down2, x_train_n2,
                          epochs=20,
                          batch_size=16,
                          validation_steps=100,
                          shuffle=True,
                          validation_split=0.15)

# Saving the Model
autoencoder.save('ISR_model_weight.h5')

# Represeting Model as JSON String
autoencoder_json = autoencoder.to_json()
with open('ISR_model.json', 'w') as json_file:
    json_file.write(autoencoder_json)
```

Error:

```
2020-09-18 20:44:23.655077: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1402] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 3891 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1650 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 7.5)
2020-09-18 20:44:23.658359: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:775] failed to allocate 3.80G (4080218880 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY: out of memory
2020-09-18 20:44:23.659070: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:775] failed to allocate 3.42G (3672196864 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY: out of memory
2020-09-18 20:44:25.560185: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "D:\GPU testing\Image Super Resolution\Image Super Resolution using Autoencoders.py", line 126, in <module>
    history = autoencoder.fit(x_train_down2, x_train_n2,

  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 108, in _method_wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)

  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1098, in fit
    tmp_logs = train_function(iterator)

  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 780, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)

  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 840, in _call
    return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)

  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 2829, in __call__
    return graph_function._filtered_call(args, kwargs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access

  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 1843, in _filtered_call
    return self._call_flat(

  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 1923, in _call_flat
    return self._build_call_outputs(self._inference_function.call(

  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 545, in call
    outputs = execute.execute(

  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py", line 59, in quick_execute
    tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,

UnknownError:  Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.
     [[node functional_1/conv2d/Relu (defined at D:\GPU testing\Image Super Resolution\Image Super Resolution using Autoencoders.py:126) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_2246]

Function call stack:
train_function

2020-09-18 20:44:19.489732: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2020-09-18 20:44:21.291233: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN)to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2020-09-18 20:44:21.306618: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x22a29eaa6b0 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-09-18 20:44:21.308804: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
2020-09-18 20:44:21.310433: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2020-09-18 20:44:22.424648: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1716] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce GTX 1650 Ti computeCapability: 7.5
coreClock: 1.485GHz coreCount: 16 deviceMemorySize: 4.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 178.84GiB/s
2020-09-18 20:44:22.425736: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2020-09-18 20:44:22.468696: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1858] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-09-18 20:44:23.161235: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1257] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2020-09-18 20:44:23.161847: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1263]      0 
2020-09-18 20:44:23.162188: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1276] 0:   N 
2020-09-18 20:44:23.162708: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1402] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 3891 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1650 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 7.5)
2020-09-18 20:44:23.167626: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x22a52959fb0 initialized for platform CUDA (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-09-18 20:44:23.168513: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): GeForce GTX 1650 Ti, Compute Capability 7.5
2020-09-18 20:44:23.642458: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1716] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce GTX 1650 Ti computeCapability: 7.5
coreClock: 1.485GHz coreCount: 16 deviceMemorySize: 4.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 178.84GiB/s
2020-09-18 20:44:23.643553: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2020-09-18 20:44:23.647378: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1858] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-09-18 20:44:23.648372: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1716] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce GTX 1650 Ti computeCapability: 7.5
coreClock: 1.485GHz coreCount: 16 deviceMemorySize: 4.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 178.84GiB/s
2020-09-18 20:44:23.649458: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2020-09-18 20:44:23.653267: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1858] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-09-18 20:44:23.653735: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1257] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2020-09-18 20:44:23.654291: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1263]      0 
2020-09-18 20:44:23.654631: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1276] 0:   N 
2020-09-18 20:44:23.655077: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1402] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 3891 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1650 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 7.5)
2020-09-18 20:44:23.658359: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:775] failed to allocate 3.80G (4080218880 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY: out of memory
2020-09-18 20:44:23.659070: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:775] failed to allocate 3.42G (3672196864 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY: out of memory
2020-09-18 20:44:25.560185: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2020-09-18 20:44:26.855418: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:328] Could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED
2020-09-18 20:44:26.856558: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:328] Could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED
2020-09-18 20:44:26.857303: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1767] OP_REQUIRES failed at conv_ops_fused_impl.h:642 : Unknown: Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.
```

I have tried GPU growth:

```
config = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session(config=config)
```

and also limiting GPU usage:

```
gpu_options = tf.compat.v1.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.95)
session = tf.compat.v1.Session(config=tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_options))
```

but they didn't resolve the issue.

I recently came across this article: What is Autoencoder? Enhance blurred images using autoencoders by Analytics Vidya, and tried the code provided and I faced the same error.

Can someone help me resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with setting GPU growth for Tensorflow 2.3.0.
After setting it properly I could get rid of the error.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.compat.v1.keras.backend import set_session

config = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
config.log_device_placement = True
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session(config=config)
set_session(sess)
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59007505/14301371

Answer (score 1):

The conv2d op raised an error message:

> Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.

Looking above, we see

> Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 3891 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1650 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 7.5)
> failed to allocate 3.80G (4080218880 bytes) from device:
> CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY: out of memory
> failed to allocate 3.42G (3672196864 bytes) from device:
> CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY: out of memory

So this graph would need more memory than there is available on your GeForce GTX 1650 Ti (3891 MB). Try using a smaller input image size and/or a smaller batch size.

Comment: I tried reducing the batch_size to 4 and input_image_size to (8, 8, 3), but still, the same error pops up.