# 'conda install tensorflow-gpu' is not installing any CUDNN libraries

Tags: tensorflow, anaconda, gpu

When I run `conda install tensorflow-gpu` in a new venv, conda gives the list of packages that it will install, but there are no CUDNN or cudatoolkit packages which I would expect, and that other people have. I am expecting an output like in this question ([Is it still necessary to install CUDA before using the conda tensorflow-gpu package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61533291/is-it-still-necessary-to-install-cuda-before-using-the-conda-tensorflow-gpu-pack?rq=1)
) but instead I get this:

[image: The packages it is installing for me, I'm expecting CUDNN]

**Edit:** I was able to get it to work by running this command instead

`conda create -n tf-gpu python=3.7 anaconda` followed by
`conda install tensorflow-gpu`

After doing this it installed all the cudnn libraries on its own and I was able to run tensorflow with GPU. However, for some reason it is installing tensorflow 1.14, and I need 2.x so does anyone know why this is?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65319255/13492054) in a previous question would solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

`conda install tensorflow-gpu` install only gpu version of Tensorflow and not supporting packages such as CUDA and cuDNN.
Follow steps to install

```
conda install cudatoolkit=10.0.130
conda install cudnn=7.6.0=cuda10.0_0
conda install tensorflow-gpu
```

Comment: I posted an edit above, I was able to get it to work by appending python=3.7 and anaconda to the creation of the virtual environment. It then installed all the cudnn and cudatoolkit libraries with the tensorflow-gpu command as expected.