# conda hangs on "solving environment"

Tags: package, conda

Whenever I try to install conda packages on WSL, it seems to hang. For example, I'm trying to run the following command on a new environment:

`conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio pytorch-cuda=11.8 -c pytorch -c nvidia`

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: |
```

Is there any way to troubleshoot why this might be happening? I tried using the `--verbose` flag after my command, but didn't get anything much more helpful:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: ...working... failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working...
```

and it continues to hang there.

Comment: Use Mamba and create new environments liberally rather than trying to install many things into one environment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How we can resolve "Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve." issue while installing the new conda package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74781771/how-we-can-resolve-solving-environment-failed-with-initial-frozen-solve-retry)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the same command, and it took me 10 minutes for solving. Try to give it a bit more time.

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked for me after I left it for around an hour (not sure when in that time it popped up). I wonder if this is an issue on my end, as I couldn't find any information about it online.