Option to try flexible install first when using ```conda install -c conda-forge PACKAGE_NAME```
I am working from an AWS SageMaker Notebook Instance. For installation of most packages for my project, conda fails to install using frozen install:
conda install -c conda-forge geopandas
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solv
e.

This takes several minutes... Is there a way to option conda to install by first trying the flexible solve?

Have you tried creating your own custom env with different solver set and using that ? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/studio-lab-use-manage.html

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74781771/how-we-can-resolve-solving-environment-failed-with-initial-frozen-solve-retry
