# Tensorflow-gpu installation with Anaconda

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

This weekend I have been trying a lot to install and get **Tensorflow with GPU support** to work on my computer, but I am not very experienced in using pip/conda and are now quite confused after watching and trying a lot of different tutorials/approaches from the web.

I have a **GeForce GTX 1650** graphics card, and I have installed **Cuda 10.0** (also 11.2, but I removed it from "PATH" and are only using the 10.0 version, I don't think that's a problem).

I have downloaded **cuDNN 7.5.0 for CUDA 10**, and I think that I have copied and placed the files correctly (installed cuDNN).

I am just trying to get some version of Tensorflow-gpu to work, but you can see the Tensorflow version i have been trying for now on the image.

I have tried to install and uninstall Python from my computer (I've also reinstalled Anaconda a lot of times), because I am not sure if I need to have a Python version installed (on my system) if I install a version of Python inside my Anaconda environment (in my example **Python 3.7**).

**Does anyone know how to install Tensorflow GPU on Windows 10 with my settings (cuDNN 7.5.0, CUDA 10), or maybe have encountered some trouble with Python versions or Anaconda problems similar to mine?**

[image]

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question but what I do is use the tensorflow docker images instead of fiddling with the installation of CUDA.

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65273118/10157759).

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to install Tensorflow GPU on windows system.

1. Make sure right version of Visual studio is installed. Check [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#system-requirements).
2. Follow the instructions mentioned [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#windows_setup) to setup CUDA for windows system
3. Install Tensorflow

> ```
> #check current python version
> python --version
> #Create the virtual environment
> conda create -n tf python=PYTHON_VERSION 
> #Activate the tf environment
> conda activate tf
> #Install Tensorflow
> pip install tensorflow
> #Install CUDA and cuDNN using conda and make sure CUDA and cuDNN version should match the Tensorflow version
> conda install -c anaconda cudatoolkit=10.0 cudnn=7.5
> ```