# Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor to Numpy array (using RTX 30xx GPU)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I've googled every error, tried many solutions and I just can't get TensorFlow to run a LSTM/ GRU network for me. I used to be able to do this.

I installed it using Anaconda in a prescribed way: `conda create -n tf-gpu tensorFlow-gpu`, I then installed jupyterlab, spyder, matplotlib, scikit-learn and pandas, nothing else. There were no compatibility errors or warnings.

I launch a notebook and try this:

```
def make_model(X_train, y_train):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(InputLayer(input_shape = (X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2])))
    model.add(GRU(units = 100))
    model.add(Dense(units = 100, activation = 'relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Dense(units = y_train.shape[1]))
    model.compile(loss = 'mse', optimizer = 'adam', metrics = 'mae')
    return model
```

But no matter what I do, I end up with this error:

```
NotImplementedError: Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor
(gru_1/strided_slice:0) to a numpy array. This error may indicate that
you're trying to pass a Tensor to a NumPy call, which is not supported
```

Everything I can find about this error points to it being a numpy version issue, I've tried downgrading to `1.18.5` using pip but that broke my environment completely. I'm trying to do so now though Anaconda and it tells me `python 3.9` is not compatible. But this goose chase is getting out of hand.

I'm not trying to do anything special as far as I can see this should just work out of the box, if not, what is the point of Anaconda? The thing is, I'm reusing code and data that I know for sure worked at one point (about 9 months ago).

Comment: Previous two answers below are inaccurate, many things were going wrong, I will make a new answer. Please upvote it so others don't have to go through my troubles!

Comment: I am facing the exact same issue as you do and am thinking exactly the same thing! Once can literally spend an entire afternoore fiddling around with conda until one ends up with an environment thats halfway working ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Final Definitive answer:

---

**Hardware:**

- Ryzen 9 5950X
- 64GB of DDR4 RAM
- RTX 3060 ti

I really wanted to work with Anaconda, as I'm very familiar with it and everything else I do works within Anaconda. On top of that, last year I got this to work within Anaconda no problem, so it had to be possible!

**Problem:**

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM
from numpy.random import rand


X, y = rand(8000, 50, 5), rand(8000, 10)

model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.Input(shape = (X.shape[1], X.shape[2])))
```

Up until here everything works fine.

The following line:

```
model.add(LSTM(units = 100))
```

Produces the following error:

```
NotImplementedError: Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor
(lstm_1/strided_slice:0) to a numpy array. This error may indicate that
you're trying to pass a Tensor to a NumPy call, which is not supported
```

**Cause / Solution:**
For a definitive answer I will have to refer you to the developers of `Tensorflow`, but I was able to deduce the following:

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66207610/1720743) has the exact same problem I did, ***it is solved by downgrading `numpy` from `1.20.x` to `1.19.x`***. The discussion on that post is an interesting read, basically `Tensorflow` version >`2.3.x` is compiled with `numpy 1.19.5`. Anaconda installs version `1.20.x` by default when using `conda install tensorflow-gpu`, they do not play nicely. Downgrading by itself is an easy enough fix.

### If you have an NVIDIA RTX 30xx GPU however you are not done!

Long story short, RTX 30xx uses the Ampere architecture, this requires a newer version of CUDA, which requires a newer version of `Tensorflow`, version >`2.4.x` to be precise. As of the time of writing, ***this version is not available on `conda`***.

Therefore all of the convenience offered by `conda`'s automatic installation of `cuDNN` and `cudatoolkit` is no longer available. Simply `pip install tensorflow=2.4.0` does not work. Worst part is, it might appear to be working until well over an hour into training something and it suddenly stops with a totally random error. (Sorry, I was ready to rage-quit at this point, it was late and didn't write down the errors, there were many, all of them led nowhere.)

[This guide](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/using-tensorflow-on-windows-10-with-nvidia-rtx-3000-series-gpus-637ab2a4b163) details in great detail how to compile cuDNN and CUDA from source. Before you follow this guide: If you go into control panel > programs and features and *uninstall everything from NVIDIA* ***that is not***: `NVIDIA graphics driver`, `NVIDIA geforce experience`, `NVIDIA HD audio driver`, `NVIDIA PhysX`.

***Another important note:***

In step *Building CUDA/cuDNN: Set 3* there is a critical typo. The guide instructs you to copy files

from:

```
# 1. cuDNN
\...\cudnn-11.0-windows-x64-v8.0.4.30.zip\cuda\bin
```

to:

```
# 2. NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit
\...\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.0\include
```

***This is incorrect!!***

it should be from:

```
# 1. cuDNN
\...\cudnn-11.0-windows-x64-v8.0.4.30.zip\cuda\bin
```

to:

```
# 2. NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit
\...\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.0\bin
```

After following this guide I ***Restarted my pc (do not skip)***, made a new environment using `python 3.8.11`:

```
conda create -n tf python=3.8
```

I installed `tensorflow 2.4.0` using `pip` directly from the command prompt and from within my new `tf` environment:

```
pip install tensorflow==2.4.0
```

This also installs `tensorflow`'s gpu capabilities as opposed to the `anaconda` version which installs cpu only when calling `conda install tensorflow`. Ofcourse, it still doesn't work, you now have `numpy 1.20.3` installed (you can check with `conda list numpy`). Simply use `conda install numpy=1.19` to downgrade it. And to top it off, on my system the example provided in the guide:

```
from tensorflow.keras import datasets, layers, models
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = datasets.cifar10.load_data()

train_images, test_images = train_images / 255.0, test_images / 255.0

model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(32, 32, 3)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(10))

model.compile(optimizer='Adam', loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True))

history = model.fit(train_images, train_labels, batch_size=10, epochs=100)
```

will throw an error (at least it does for me):

```
NotFoundError:  No algorithm worked!
     [[node sequential/conv2d/Relu (defined at <ipython-input-1-bf665ec77ee4>:18) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_580]
```

However, we are not interested in this example, we want to run LSTM / GRU, and ***not bug-fix this example***. Therefore we will discard this and carry on, now we will try:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM
from numpy.random import rand


X, y = rand(8000, 50, 5), rand(8000, 10)

model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.Input(shape = (X.shape[1], X.shape[2])))           

model.add(LSTM(units = 100))
model.add(Dense(units = 10))
```

Low and behold, no error!

```
model.compile(loss = 'mse', optimizer = 'adam')
```

Still no error!

```
history = model.fit(X, y, epochs = 10)
```

Still no error!, is it even using the GPU? The messages in the console certainly seem to indicate so:

```
2021-08-19 13:04:09.234795: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
Default GPU Device: /device:GPU:0
training model

2021-08-19 13:04:09.234795: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
2021-08-19 13:04:10.645028: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2021-08-19 13:04:10.647857: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2021-08-19 13:04:10.662783: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:0a:00.0 name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Ti computeCapability: 8.6
coreClock: 1.755GHz coreCount: 38 deviceMemorySize: 8.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 417.29GiB/s
2021-08-19 13:04:10.662799: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
2021-08-19 13:04:10.667119: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_11.dll
2021-08-19 13:04:10.667133: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublasLt64_11.dll
2021-08-19 13:04:10.669347: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2021-08-19 13:04:10.670066: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2021-08-19 13:04:10.675548: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2021-08-19 13:04:10.677202: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_11.dll
2021-08-19 13:04:10.677612: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_8.dll
2021-08-19 13:04:10.677658: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1862] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2021-08-19 13:04:10.979738: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1261] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2021-08-19 13:04:10.979763: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1267]      0 
2021-08-19 13:04:10.979770: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1280] 0:   N 
2021-08-19 13:04:10.979886: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1406] Created TensorFlow device (/device:GPU:0 with 6617 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:0a:00.0, compute capability: 8.6)
2021-08-19 13:04:10.980387: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_gpu_device.cc:99] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
2021-08-19 13:04:10.980542: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:0a:00.0 name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Ti computeCapability: 8.6
coreClock: 1.755GHz coreCount: 38 deviceMemorySize: 8.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 417.29GiB/s
2021-08-19 13:04:10.980555: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
2021-08-19 13:04:10.980563: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_11.dll
2021-08-19 13:04:10.980569: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublasLt64_11.dll
2021-08-19 13:04:10.980575: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2021-08-19 13:04:10.980580: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2021-08-19 13:04:10.980586: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2021-08-19 13:04:10.980592: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_11.dll
2021-08-19 13:04:10.980646: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_8.dll
2021-08-19 13:04:10.980676: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1862] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2021-08-19 13:04:10.980693: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1261] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2021-08-19 13:04:10.980698: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1267]      0 
2021-08-19 13:04:10.980703: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1280] 0:   N 
2021-08-19 13:04:10.980744: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1406] Created TensorFlow device (/device:GPU:0 with 6617 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:0a:00.0, compute capability: 8.6)
2021-08-19 13:04:10.980757: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_gpu_device.cc:99] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
2021-08-19 13:04:10.984016: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_cpu_device.cc:41] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
2021-08-19 13:04:10.984082: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:0a:00.0 name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Ti computeCapability: 8.6
coreClock: 1.755GHz coreCount: 38 deviceMemorySize: 8.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 417.29GiB/s
2021-08-19 13:04:10.984094: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
2021-08-19 13:04:10.984100: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_11.dll
2021-08-19 13:04:10.984106: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublasLt64_11.dll
2021-08-19 13:04:10.984112: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2021-08-19 13:04:10.984117: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2021-08-19 13:04:10.984122: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2021-08-19 13:04:10.984127: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_11.dll
2021-08-19 13:04:10.984132: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_8.dll
2021-08-19 13:04:10.984158: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1862] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2021-08-19 13:04:10.984332: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:0a:00.0 name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Ti computeCapability: 8.6
coreClock: 1.755GHz coreCount: 38 deviceMemorySize: 8.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 417.29GiB/s
2021-08-19 13:04:10.984344: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
2021-08-19 13:04:10.984350: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_11.dll
2021-08-19 13:04:10.984355: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublasLt64_11.dll
2021-08-19 13:04:10.984360: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2021-08-19 13:04:10.984365: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2021-08-19 13:04:10.984369: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2021-08-19 13:04:10.984374: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_11.dll
2021-08-19 13:04:10.984420: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_8.dll
2021-08-19 13:04:10.984445: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1862] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2021-08-19 13:04:10.984470: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1261] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2021-08-19 13:04:10.984475: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1267]      0 
2021-08-19 13:04:10.984479: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1280] 0:   N 
2021-08-19 13:04:10.984533: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1406] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 6617 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:0a:00.0, compute capability: 8.6)
2021-08-19 13:04:10.984546: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_gpu_device.cc:99] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
2021-08-19 13:04:11.334311: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:116] None of the MLIR optimization passes are enabled (registered 2)
```

When looking at the task manager, I can see the memory being fully allocated and the 3D graph showing 99% utilization! The training time required has been quartered compared to using the CPU. All in all, great success!

I now really hope that running a Conv2D network of my own design won't result in the same error the example was having, but only time will tell, for now this is good enough for my purposes.

Answer (score 1):

I started over in a new environment, this time installed tensorflow-gpu using `conda install tensorflow-gpu` instead of downloading a complete environment. After downgrading numpy to 1.18.5 using `conda install numpy=1.18.5` it appears to be working!, but now tensorflow does not detect my gpu...

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> print(tf.config.list_physical_devices())
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:CPU:0', device_type='CPU')]
```

I've followed [this guide](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/solution-to-tensorflow-2-not-using-gpu-119fb3e04daa) and came to the conclusion that conda did not install cudnn or cudatoolkit. Running `nvcc -V` in a command prompt yielded this output:

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2021 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Wed_Jun__2_19:25:35_Pacific_Daylight_Time_2021
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.4, V11.4.48
Build cuda_11.4.r11.4/compiler.30033411_0
```

The guide calls for using `conda search cudnn` and matching the build number provided to the build number listed by `nvcc -V` so in my case: `release 11.4`. Of-course when I run `conda search cudnn` I get this:

```
# Name                       Version           Build  Channel
cudnn                          7.1.4       cuda8.0_0  pkgs/main
cudnn                          7.1.4       cuda9.0_0  pkgs/main
cudnn                          7.3.1      cuda10.0_0  pkgs/main
cudnn                          7.3.1       cuda9.0_0  pkgs/main
cudnn                          7.6.0      cuda10.0_0  pkgs/main
cudnn                          7.6.0      cuda10.1_0  pkgs/main
cudnn                          7.6.0       cuda9.0_0  pkgs/main
cudnn                          7.6.4      cuda10.0_0  pkgs/main
cudnn                          7.6.4      cuda10.1_0  pkgs/main
cudnn                          7.6.4       cuda9.0_0  pkgs/main
cudnn                          7.6.5      cuda10.0_0  pkgs/main
cudnn                          7.6.5      cuda10.1_0  pkgs/main
cudnn                          7.6.5      cuda10.2_0  pkgs/main
cudnn                          7.6.5       cuda9.0_0  pkgs/main
cudnn                          7.6.5       cuda9.2_0  pkgs/main
cudnn                          8.2.1      cuda11.3_0  pkgs/main
```

Being out of options I decided to install 8.2.1 for build cuda11.3_0 in a new environment and install tensorflow-gpu afterwards, and to no-ones surprise, that doesn't work.

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> print(tf.config.list_physical_devices())
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:CPU:0', device_type='CPU')]
```

So I downloaded the cuda 11.3 driver from [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-11.3.0-download-archive?target_os=Windows&target_arch=x86_64&target_version=10&target_type=exe_local), but when I run `nvcc -V` the output remains unchanged. I'm considering running DisplayDriverUninstaller and trying again. But this is a ridiculous amount of effort to get tensorflow-gpu working, and its 2 versions behind the most recent release!

My hardware:
AMD Ryzen 9 5950x
NVIDIA RTX 3060 ti
64GB of DDR4 RAM

I'm writing this before actually trying DDU because I don't have access to the physical machine right now. I will post back tomorrow with an update if it changed anything.

Answer (score 1):

A totally different solution to this problem can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65319255/1720743). I think that this won't be good enough for many people, but since I have a simple goal for today I'm going to take the win.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Make a new environment with python 3.7
2. Install Cuda 10.1
3. Restart pc (do not skip this!)
4. in the new environment run `conda install tensorflow-gpu=2.1`
5. then run `pip install tensorflow-gpu==2.3`

Congratulations, if you have the same (and still unknown) problem I was having it should now be solved. Keep in mind that many other libraries (or updates to them) that don't work with python <3.8 are now off the table and the tensorflow version you'll be using is a year old.

Additionally, the tensorflow library (non -gpu) is still at version 2.1 in my environment. But I'm going to stop here and leave that experiment to someone else before I break the environment again.

**edit:** Turns out it only works from command prompt and crashes with no error. Tried from spyder's Ipython console thingy (not sure how that works to be honest), didn't work.

Comment: Thank you very much. Numpy v1.20.x seemed to be the problem, downgrading to v1.19.0 solved the issue for me.