# Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning [Op:Conv2D]

Tags: tensorflow, convolution

I am configuring a GitHub repo and there are requirements that are mentioned below. Still, I get an error: For GeForce RTX 2070

```
cudatoolkit=10.1.243=h6bb024c_0
cudnn=7.6.5=cuda10.1_0
tensorboard=1.14.0=py36hf484d3e_0
tensorflow=1.14.0=gpu_py36h3fb9ad6_0
tensorflow-base=1.14.0=gpu_py36he45bfe2_0
tensorflow-estimator=1.14.0=py_0
tensorflow-gpu=1.14.0=h0d30ee6_0
```

**Traceback (most recent call last):**

```
  File "/home/khawar/Desktop/AAAIFace/train_main.py", line 60, in <module>
    losses, loss_grad, tape = network.lossFunc(img_batch, age_batch, gender_batch, AIM_model)
  File "/home/khawar/Desktop/AAAIFace/network.py", line 139, in lossFunc
    z_enc = AIM.encoder(img)
  File "/home/khawar/Desktop/AAAIFace/modeleag.py", line 126, in __call__
    res = self.forward(x, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/khawar/Desktop/AAAIFace/network.py", line 23, in forward
    x = self.c1(x)
  File "/home/khawar/Desktop/AAAIFace/modeleag.py", line 126, in __call__
    res = self.forward(x, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/khawar/Desktop/AAAIFace/modeleag.py", line 143, in forward
    x = self.conv(x)
  File "/home/khawar/Desktop/AAAIFace/layers2.py", line 78, in __call__
    return self._deploy()
  File "/home/khawar/Desktop/AAAIFace/layers2.py", line 153, in _deploy
    out = tf.nn.conv2d(self.x, self.W, self.stride, self.pad, dilations=self.dilation_rate)
  File "/home/khawar/anaconda3/envs/AAAIFace/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py", line 1953, in conv2d
    name=name)
  File "/home/khawar/anaconda3/envs/AAAIFace/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_nn_ops.py", line 1039, in conv2d
    _six.raise_from(_core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnknownError: Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above. [Op:Conv2D]
```

Comment: Make sure you have only 1 instance of python running

Comment: Yes, only one is running.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53698035/failed-to-get-convolution-algorithm-this-is-probably-because-cudnn-failed-to-in)

Comment: I already checked this answer when I do these steps then training is going on the CPU.